# Merge array of hashes with validation

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I would like to merge one array of hashes with another if some of the keys match. For instance, I have this:

```
data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7}]
new_data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "z"=>10}]
```

Running some method, like this:

```
merge_with_validation(data, new_data, ["a","b"])
```

I want the result to be this:

```
[{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "z"=>10}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7, "z"=>nil}]
```

So the result is `data` merged with `new_data` when the values in keys `a` and `b` match.

---

**Answer Update**

I got it to work using Arup Rakshit's answer with a little change :

```
def merge_with_validation(data, new_data, keys)
  data.map do |hash|
    if hash.values_at(*keys) ==  new_data.first.values_at(*keys)
      next hash.merge(new_data.shift)
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

Comment: The question is not clear, how is value of key `a` being caluclated as 2? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: On top of that, your second form of the expected result is invalid.

Comment: On top of that, `merge` is an operation on a hash, not on an array. Your last sentence does not make sense.

Comment: Corrected the expected result

Comment: Can you have multiple hashes in `new_data`?

Comment: Yes, i could have this `new_data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "z"=>10},{"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "z"=>10}]`. In this case data[1] would be `[{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "z"=>10}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7, "z"=>10}]`

Comment: Don't put answers in the question, even if it is how your code ended up looking. Questions are for that only, the question. IF your code is unique and does something not shown in any other answer then it'd be appropriate to add it as an separate answer, possibly even selecting it as the accepted answer, but only if it adds sufficient value, and, in that case, explain why it's better and should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do

```
data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7}]
new_data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "z"=>10}]

def merge_with_validation(data, new_data, keys)
    data.map do |hash|
       if hash.values_at(*keys) ==  new_data.first.values_at(*keys)
           next hash.merge(new_data.first)
       end
       hash.merge({"z"=>nil})
    end
end

merge_with_validation(data, new_data, ["a","b"]) 
# => [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "z"=>10}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7, "z" => nil}]
```

Comment: Great use of `values_at`! :-) +1

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Your code met my needs. I have just made one change, where you put `hash.merge({"z"=>nil})` I replaced with `hash` because I don't really need the nil value if the line isn't a match.

Comment: @victorkohl Yes, if you don't need `"z" => nil}` ,just do `hash` instead of `hash.merge({"z"=>nil})`.

Comment: Another change was at `next hash.merge(new_data.first)` I changed with `next hash.merge(new_data.shift)`, so `new_data` could have multiple hashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Note that we're not checking for missing keys (i.e. "z") programmatically but we could do this

```
def merge_with_validation(data, new_data, keys)
    data.each_with_object([]).with_index { |(e,arr), i| 
       new_hash = new_data[i] || e
       new_hash["z"] = nil if !new_hash["z"]
       arr << e.merge(new_hash) if keys.all? { |k| e[k] ==  new_hash[k]} 
    }
end
```

Returns:

```
merge_with_validation(data,new_data, %w(a b))
=> [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "z"=>10}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7, "z"=>nil}]
```

Let me know if you find bugs and I'll fix (I'm running late for soccer :-))

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This code works for the example I provided, but when it doesn't match some line, the remaining won't be merged. For example: `data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7}]` and `new_data = [{"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "z"=>10}]`. The expected result would be `[{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7, "z"=10}]` but it returns  only the rows in `data` that were matched (`{"a"=>1, "b"=>5, "c"=>7, "z"=10}]`).

Comment: I see you want to merge while doing some sort of combination.. My fix won't work unless I do the next shift as you did above.. I'll delete :-)